# Android -- how to programmatically change (not set for the first time) LinearLayout's height and topMargin?

Tags: java, android

If I set  LL's topMargin for the **first** time, it works OK.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bar.getLayoutParams());
lp.height = MAX_HEIGHT * values.get(i)/MAX_VAL;
bar.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

As for xml, it is basically LL (bar) within LL.
When I try invoking this code for the **second** time, nothing changes **visually** (LogCat shows that height changes though). 
I tried playing with **invalidate()**, **requestLayout()**, **forceLayout()** methods -- nothing happens. Googling didn't help -- people seem to have different issues. Please help.

Edit: Yes, it is invoked on UI thread, consequentely postInvalidate() does not work.

Comment: Do you run this code on the UI Thread?

Comment: You should postInvalidate if you're not on the UI thread. And when you change the object's layoutparams, relayout its parent so it calculate the new size of the object. But breakpoints in onLayout et onMeasure to check this :)